# How can I store output from a for loop in a list?

Tags: r, loops

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to=100, by=20)){
    print(i)
    job <- print(paste(progexe, i, 20, "-g", configfile))
}
```

Line 3 produces 4 sentences (basically commands for Bash) in the loop which I want to store in a list.

If I make `job[i]` then of course I am left with lots of NULL values.

I can remove null values but is there another way to do this?

If I use `seq_along`, then it changes the increment of the loop, which is not what I want.

Comment: `sapply(v, function(i) paste(progexe, i, 20, "-g", configfile))` Go through an R tutorial and you'll get used to this idiom (where `v` is the vector you're iterating over).

Comment: @Frank Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Frank 's idea is better but you can avoid the nulls with `i  %/% 20 + 1`.

Comment: Np. Actually, since `paste` is vectorized, I guess it should be `paste(progexe, v, 20, "-g", configfile)` without need for a loop or `sapply`. You might also want to look at `?sprintf`.

Comment: Even simpler. Thanks!

Comment: use should be doing this using `purrr` from `tidyverse`